# How to prevent open file twice?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have an `Mdi application`.
This application allowed to open the text files in `subWindow`.
The problem is you can open the same file many times.

[image]

I have used the following incomplete code:

```
QList<QMdiSubWindow*> subWindows = ui->mdiArea->subWindowList()
```

But how can I know if the file exists or not.

**How can I prevent this behavior ?**

---

**Modification**

**I have doing the following code, and it is works fine: (`Please review the code`)**

```
QList <QMdiSubWindow*> subWindows = ui -> mdiArea -> subWindowList();
if (subWindows.count() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < subWindows.count(); i++) {
        if (subWindows.at(i) -> property("filePath").toString() == fileDlg) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Full Code:**

```
QString fileDlg = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open File", "F://", "Text Files(*.txt)");
if (fileDlg != "") {

    // Start the important code
    QList < QMdiSubWindow * > subWindows = ui -> mdiArea -> subWindowList();
    if (subWindows.count() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < subWindows.count(); i++) {
            if (subWindows.at(i) -> property("filePath").toString() == fileDlg) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // End the important code  

    QString cache;
    QFile file(fileDlg);
    if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in ( & file);
        while (!file.atEnd()) {
            cache = in .readAll();
        }
    }
    file.close();


    QFileInfo finfo(file);
    QWidget * widget = new QWidget(this);
    QTextEdit * TextEdit = new QTextEdit(widget);
    TextEdit -> setObjectName("myTextEdit");
    QMdiSubWindow * mdiWindows = ui -> mdiArea - > addSubWindow(widget);
    mdiWindows -> setProperty("filePath", fileDlg);
    mdiWindows -> setGeometry(5, 5, 300, 250);
    mdiWindows -> setWindowTitle(finfo.baseName());
    mdiWindows -> layout() -> addWidget(TextEdit);
    mdiWindows -> setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
    mdiWindows -> layout() -> setSpacing(0);
    TextEdit -> setText(cache);
    mdiWindows -> show();
}
```

Comment: use a container to maintain a list of opened files, when open a new file check whether the file to open is in the list of opened file.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating system, the same file can have several different names. Even the same name can be referred to in different ways (think traversing the directory structure!). Any purely name-based scheme is bound to fail.

Doing this is often even quite useful, I often have the same file open several times, to look at one place while editing another. Let the user decide.

Answer (score 0):

Example code as required:

```
class MdiWindow 
{
    static std::vector<std::wstring> s_filePaths;
    bool openNewFile(const std::wstring& filePath) {
        std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = std::find(s_filePaths.begin(), s_filePaths.end(), filePath);
        //already opened
        if (iter != s_filePaths.end()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (openFileSucceeded(filePath)) {
            s_filePaths.push_back(filePath);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    void closeFile(const std::wstring& filePath) {
        s_filePaths.erase(s_filePaths.begin(), std::remove(s_filePaths.begin(), s_filePaths.end(), filePath));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this. It has platform-dependent solutions by interrogating kernel data structures and looking in to per-process structures which is not easy.

But you can have opened files by your application in a container and check it's values when opening a new file.

The container can be a class member like :

```
QList<QString> openedFileNames;
```

Opening a file :

```
if(!openedFileNames.contains(filename))
{
    openedFileNames.append(filename);

    QFile file( filename );

    if( !file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
        QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Error opening!"), tr("Could not open the file"));

    ...
}
```

Closing a file :

```
openedFileNames.removeAt(openedFileNames.indexOf(filename));
file.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Mr `@Nejat` for help me, I have solved the problem. please review my code to see if my code is good or bad. look at my question again I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

After open first time, use:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlockfile.html

In your code add:

```
QFile file(fileDlg);
if (file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    QTextStream in ( & file);
    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        cache = in .readAll();
    }
} else {
    //Something...
    return;
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, but How to use `QLockFile` class. I have done `QLockFile lockFile(fileDlg); lockFile.lock();`.

Comment: @LionKing unfortunately I am unable to block the reading. I'll try again tomorrow.